# Amazon RDS MySQL high CPU issues

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, cpu

I am hoping for a bit of help or direction on how best to troubleshoot this issue. We have recently increased our application load (more processes interacting with the DB) and the DB CPU is constantly between 30-90% sometimes going to 100%. This even happens during non busy times.

Here is some data taken from right now during a low traffic time where the CPU is sitting around 30% which seems high.

Any help would be much appreciated!

This is on an Amazon RDS db.t2.medium which has 4GB ram.

CPU 5 mins:
[image: CPU 5 minutes]

Performance Insights:
[image]

[image]

[image]

SHOW VARIABLES:

```
auto_increment_increment    1
auto_increment_offset   1
autocommit  ON
automatic_sp_privileges ON
avoid_temporal_upgrade  OFF
back_log    112
basedir /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.51.R2/
big_tables  OFF
bind_address    *
binlog_cache_size   32768
binlog_checksum CRC32
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF
binlog_error_action IGNORE_ERROR
binlog_format   MIXED
binlog_gtid_simple_recovery OFF
binlog_max_flush_queue_time 0
binlog_order_commits    ON
binlog_row_image    FULL
binlog_rows_query_log_events    OFF
binlog_stmt_cache_size  32768
binlogging_impossible_mode  IGNORE_ERROR
block_encryption_mode   aes-128-ecb
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608
character_set_client    utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8mb4
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.51.R2/share/charsets/
collation_connection    utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci
completion_type NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert   AUTO
connect_timeout 10
core_file   OFF
datadir /rdsdbdata/db/
date_format %Y-%m-%d
datetime_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
default_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_week_format 0
delay_key_write ON
delayed_insert_limit    100
delayed_insert_timeout  300
delayed_queue_size  1000
disconnect_on_expired_password  ON
div_precision_increment 4
end_markers_in_json OFF
enforce_gtid_consistency    OFF
eq_range_index_dive_limit   10
error_count 0
event_scheduler OFF
expire_logs_days    0
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp ON
external_user   
flush   OFF
flush_time  0
foreign_key_checks  ON
ft_boolean_syntax   + -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len 84
ft_min_word_len 4
ft_query_expansion_limit    20
ft_stopword_file    (built-in)
general_log ON
general_log_file    /rdsdbdata/log/general/mysql-general.log
group_concat_max_len    1024
gtid_executed   
gtid_mode   OFF
gtid_next   AUTOMATIC
gtid_owned  
gtid_purged 
have_compress   YES
have_crypt  YES
have_dynamic_loading    YES
have_geometry   YES
have_openssl    YES
have_profiling  YES
have_query_cache    YES
have_rtree_keys YES
have_ssl    YES
have_symlink    YES
host_cache_size 440
hostname    ip-10-6-0-128
identity    0
ignore_builtin_innodb   OFF
ignore_db_dirs  
init_connect    
init_file   
init_slave  
innodb_adaptive_flushing    ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm    10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size 8388608
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval   5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock  OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog    OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl   OFF
innodb_api_trx_level    0
innodb_autoextend_increment 64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size 2147483648
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25
innodb_change_buffering all
innodb_checksum_algorithm   innodb
innodb_checksums    ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled    OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct    5
innodb_compression_level    6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max  50
innodb_concurrency_tickets  5000
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir    /rdsdbdata/db/innodb
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache  OFF
innodb_doublewrite  ON
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_file_format  Antelope
innodb_file_format_check    ON
innodb_file_format_max  Antelope
innodb_file_per_table   ON
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  1
innodb_flush_method O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_neighbors  1
innodb_flushing_avg_loops   30
innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_ft_aux_table 
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size    84
innodb_ft_min_token_size    3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table 
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree   2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size  640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table   
innodb_io_capacity  200
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000
innodb_large_prefix OFF
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size  8388608
innodb_log_compressed_pages ON
innodb_log_file_size    134217728
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_log_group_home_dir   /rdsdbdata/log/innodb
innodb_lru_scan_depth   1024
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  75
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  0
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay  0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups  1
innodb_monitor_disable  
innodb_monitor_enable   
innodb_monitor_reset    
innodb_monitor_reset_all    
innodb_numa_interleave  OFF
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size    134217728
innodb_open_files   2000
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only   OFF
innodb_page_size    16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks  OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size 300
innodb_purge_threads    1
innodb_random_read_ahead    OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56
innodb_read_io_threads  4
innodb_read_only    OFF
innodb_replication_delay    0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
innodb_rollback_segments    128
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay  6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc    ON
innodb_stats_include_delete_marked  OFF
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata    OFF
innodb_stats_persistent ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages    20
innodb_stats_sample_pages   8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8
innodb_status_output    OFF
innodb_status_output_locks  OFF
innodb_strict_mode  OFF
innodb_support_xa   ON
innodb_sync_array_size  1
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30
innodb_table_locks  ON
innodb_thread_concurrency   0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   10000
innodb_tmpdir   
innodb_undo_directory   .
innodb_undo_logs    128
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0
innodb_use_native_aio   ON
innodb_use_sys_malloc   ON
innodb_version  5.6.51
innodb_write_io_threads 4
insert_id   0
interactive_timeout 28800
join_buffer_size    262144
keep_files_on_create    OFF
key_buffer_size 16777216
key_cache_age_threshold 300
key_cache_block_size    1024
key_cache_division_limit    100
large_files_support ON
large_page_size 0
large_pages OFF
last_insert_id  0
lc_messages en_US
lc_messages_dir /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.51.R2/share/
lc_time_names   en_US
license GPL
local_infile    ON
lock_wait_timeout   31536000
locked_in_memory    OFF
log_bin ON
log_bin_basename    /rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog
log_bin_index   /rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog.index
log_bin_trust_function_creators OFF
log_bin_use_v1_row_events   OFF
log_error   /rdsdbdata/log/error/mysql-error.log
log_output  TABLE
log_queries_not_using_indexes   OFF
log_slave_updates   ON
log_slow_admin_statements   OFF
log_slow_slave_statements   OFF
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes  0
log_warnings    1
long_query_time 10.000000
low_priority_updates    OFF
lower_case_file_system  OFF
lower_case_table_names  0
master_info_repository  TABLE
master_verify_checksum  OFF
max_allowed_packet  4194304
max_binlog_cache_size   18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size 134217728
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size  18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors  100
max_connections 312
max_delayed_threads 20
max_digest_length   1024
max_error_count 64
max_heap_table_size 16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads  20
max_join_size   18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data    1024
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382
max_relay_log_size  0
max_seeks_for_key   18446744073709551615
max_sort_length 1024
max_sp_recursion_depth  0
max_tmp_tables  32
max_user_connections    0
max_write_lock_count    18446744073709551615
metadata_locks_cache_size   1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances   8
min_examined_row_limit  0
multi_range_count   256
myisam_data_pointer_size    6
myisam_max_sort_file_size   9223372036853727232
myisam_mmap_size    18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options  OFF
myisam_repair_threads   1
myisam_sort_buffer_size 8388608
myisam_stats_method nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap OFF
net_buffer_length   16384
net_read_timeout    30
net_retry_count 10
net_write_timeout   60
new OFF
old OFF
old_alter_table OFF
old_passwords   0
open_files_limit    65535
optimizer_prune_level   1
optimizer_search_depth  62
optimizer_switch    index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on
optimizer_trace enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features    greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on
optimizer_trace_limit   1
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size    16384
optimizer_trace_offset  -1
performance_schema  OFF
performance_schema_accounts_size    -1
performance_schema_digests_size -1
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size  -1
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size   -1
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size  -1
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size   -1
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size   -1
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size    -1
performance_schema_hosts_size   -1
performance_schema_max_cond_classes 80
performance_schema_max_cond_instances   -1
performance_schema_max_digest_length    1024
performance_schema_max_file_classes 50
performance_schema_max_file_handles 32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances   -1
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes    200
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes   40
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances -1
performance_schema_max_socket_classes   10
performance_schema_max_socket_instances -1
performance_schema_max_stage_classes    150
performance_schema_max_statement_classes    168
performance_schema_max_table_handles    -1
performance_schema_max_table_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_thread_classes   50
performance_schema_max_thread_instances -1
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size   -1
performance_schema_setup_actors_size    100
performance_schema_setup_objects_size   100
performance_schema_users_size   -1
pid_file    /rdsdbdata/log/mysql-3306.pid
plugin_dir  /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.51.R2/lib/plugin/
port    3306
preload_buffer_size 32768
profiling   OFF
profiling_history_size  15
protocol_version    10
proxy_user  
pseudo_slave_mode   OFF
pseudo_thread_id    8309994
query_alloc_block_size  8192
query_cache_limit   1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096
query_cache_size    1048576
query_cache_type    OFF
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF
query_prealloc_size 8192
rand_seed1  0
rand_seed2  0
range_alloc_block_size  4096
read_buffer_size    262144
read_only   OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size    524288
relay_log   /rdsdbdata/log/relaylog/relaylog
relay_log_basename  /rdsdbdata/log/relaylog/relaylog
relay_log_index /rdsdbdata/log/relaylog/relaylog.index
relay_log_info_file relay-log.info
relay_log_info_repository   TABLE
relay_log_purge ON
relay_log_recovery  ON
relay_log_space_limit   0
report_host 
report_password 
report_port 3306
report_user 
rpl_stop_slave_timeout  31536000
secure_auth ON
secure_file_priv    /secure_file_priv_dir/
server_id_bits  32
sha256_password_private_key_path    private_key.pem
sha256_password_public_key_path public_key.pem
show_old_temporals  OFF
simplified_binlog_gtid_recovery OFF
skip_external_locking   ON
skip_name_resolve   OFF
skip_networking OFF
skip_show_database  OFF
slave_allow_batching    OFF
slave_checkpoint_group  512
slave_checkpoint_period 300
slave_compressed_protocol   OFF
slave_exec_mode STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir   /rdsdbdata/tmp
slave_max_allowed_packet    1073741824
slave_net_timeout   3600
slave_parallel_workers  0
slave_pending_jobs_size_max 16777216
slave_rows_search_algorithms    TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
slave_skip_errors   OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum   ON
slave_transaction_retries   10
slave_type_conversions  
slow_launch_time    2
slow_query_log  ON
slow_query_log_file /rdsdbdata/log/slowquery/mysql-slowquery.log
socket  /tmp/mysql.sock
sort_buffer_size    262144
sql_auto_is_null    OFF
sql_big_selects ON
sql_buffer_result   OFF
sql_log_bin ON
sql_log_off OFF
sql_mode    NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_notes   ON
sql_quote_show_create   ON
sql_safe_updates    OFF
sql_select_limit    18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter  0
sql_warnings    OFF
ssl_ca  /rdsdbdata/rds-metadata/ca-cert.pem
ssl_capath  
ssl_crl 
ssl_crlpath 
ssl_key /rdsdbdata/rds-metadata/server-key.pem
storage_engine  InnoDB
stored_program_cache    256
sync_binlog 1
sync_frm    ON
sync_master_info    10000
sync_relay_log  10000
sync_relay_log_info 10000
system_time_zone    UTC
table_definition_cache  1400
table_open_cache    2000
table_open_cache_instances  16
thread_cache_size   11
thread_concurrency  10
thread_handling one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack    262144
time_format %H:%i:%s
time_zone   UTC
timed_mutexes   OFF
timestamp   1633945555.192778
tmp_table_size  16777216
tmpdir  /rdsdbdata/tmp
transaction_alloc_block_size    8192
transaction_allow_batching  OFF
transaction_prealloc_size   4096
tx_isolation    REPEATABLE-READ
tx_read_only    OFF
unique_checks   ON
updatable_views_with_limit  YES
version 5.6.51-log
version_comment Source distribution
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Linux
wait_timeout    28800
warning_count   0
```

SHOW GLOBAL STATUS:

```
Aborted_clients 224
Aborted_connects    7
Binlog_cache_disk_use   13885
Binlog_cache_use    37525824
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   54
Bytes_received  91969030573
Bytes_sent  831135077234
Com_admin_commands  341454
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_alter_db    1
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event 0
Com_alter_function  0
Com_alter_procedure 0
Com_alter_server    0
Com_alter_table 10
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_alter_user  0
Com_analyze 0
Com_begin   11630165
Com_binlog  0
Com_call_procedure  108
Com_change_db   8454133
Com_change_master   0
Com_check   0
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit  11656257
Com_create_db   0
Com_create_event    0
Com_create_function 0
Com_create_index    0
Com_create_procedure    0
Com_create_server   0
Com_create_table    221
Com_create_trigger  3
Com_create_udf  0
Com_create_user 1
Com_create_view 0
Com_dealloc_sql 0
Com_delete  3400698
Com_delete_multi    0
Com_do  0
Com_drop_db 0
Com_drop_event  0
Com_drop_function   0
Com_drop_index  0
Com_drop_procedure  0
Com_drop_server 0
Com_drop_table  108
Com_drop_trigger    3
Com_drop_user   0
Com_drop_view   0
Com_empty_query 0
Com_execute_sql 0
Com_flush   27883
Com_get_diagnostics 0
Com_grant   18
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open 0
Com_ha_read 0
Com_help    0
Com_insert  31121661
Com_insert_select   0
Com_install_plugin  0
Com_kill    20
Com_load    0
Com_lock_tables 0
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys    0
Com_prepare_sql 0
Com_purge   0
Com_purge_before_date   26668
Com_release_savepoint   0
Com_rename_table    108
Com_rename_user 0
Com_repair  0
Com_replace 0
Com_replace_select  0
Com_reset   0
Com_resignal    0
Com_revoke  0
Com_revoke_all  0
Com_rollback    258
Com_rollback_to_savepoint   0
Com_savepoint   0
Com_select  499230264
Com_set_option  16918324
Com_signal  0
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs    0
Com_show_charsets   0
Com_show_collations 15
Com_show_create_db  0
Com_show_create_event   0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    0
Com_show_create_table   1471
Com_show_create_trigger 6
Com_show_databases  37
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex   0
Com_show_engine_status  0
Com_show_events 0
Com_show_errors 0
Com_show_fields 2640
Com_show_function_code  0
Com_show_function_status    2222
Com_show_grants 0
Com_show_keys   66
Com_show_master_status  94
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins    0
Com_show_privileges 5
Com_show_procedure_code 0
Com_show_procedure_status   2222
Com_show_processlist    16
Com_show_profile    0
Com_show_profiles   0
Com_show_relaylog_events    0
Com_show_slave_hosts    0
Com_show_slave_status   0
Com_show_status 25813
Com_show_storage_engines    0
Com_show_table_status   1281
Com_show_tables 133
Com_show_triggers   78
Com_show_variables  27127
Com_show_warnings   0
Com_slave_start 0
Com_slave_stop  0
Com_stmt_close  548198203
Com_stmt_execute    548201999
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    548198258
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
Com_truncate    0
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables   94
Com_update  3012055
Com_update_multi    0
Com_xa_commit   0
Com_xa_end  0
Com_xa_prepare  0
Com_xa_recover  0
Com_xa_rollback 0
Com_xa_start    0
Compression ON
Connection_errors_accept    0
Connection_errors_internal  0
Connection_errors_max_connections   0
Connection_errors_peer_address  0
Connection_errors_select    0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap   0
Connections 8513880
Created_tmp_disk_tables 249491
Created_tmp_files   7357
Created_tmp_tables  1346548
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  586246359
Handler_delete  7949704
Handler_discover    0
Handler_external_lock   4484763053
Handler_mrr_init    0
Handler_prepare 83925600
Handler_read_first  20511064
Handler_read_key    12146691384
Handler_read_last   34185
Handler_read_next   39950964685
Handler_read_prev   108322687
Handler_read_rnd    401683386
Handler_read_rnd_next   1373484563921
Handler_rollback    255
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  1386472965
Handler_write   2029288900
Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status  not started
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status  not started
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   115303
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   1889124352
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  17
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  278528
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    74268160
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   8192
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   7577
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  131072
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   2568118
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   72
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    481639951408
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    40255197
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   471798585
Innodb_data_fsyncs  92035141
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  0
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    779905077248
Innodb_data_reads   47602361
Innodb_data_writes  137276892
Innodb_data_written 2491009225216
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  74268160
Innodb_dblwr_writes 18935100
Innodb_have_atomic_builtins ON
Innodb_log_waits    0
Innodb_log_write_requests   78536655
Innodb_log_writes   42461024
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    44088646
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   56568371200
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    466464
Innodb_pages_read   47601646
Innodb_pages_written    74268160
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    43883
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    8
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    581
Innodb_row_lock_waits   5306
Innodb_rows_deleted 7950479
Innodb_rows_inserted    45936087
Innodb_rows_read    1419328080942
Innodb_rows_updated 5392831
Innodb_num_open_files   101
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
Innodb_available_undo_logs  128
Key_blocks_not_flushed  0
Key_blocks_unused   13389
Key_blocks_used 25
Key_read_requests   323681
Key_reads   633
Key_write_requests  496
Key_writes  119
Last_query_cost 0.000000
Last_query_partial_plans    0
Max_used_connections    47
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Open_files  152
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  263
Open_tables 1793
Opened_files    1362637
Opened_table_definitions    2584
Opened_tables   7341
Performance_schema_accounts_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_digest_lost  0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_hosts_lost   0
Performance_schema_locker_lost  0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost   0
Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_users_lost   0
Prepared_stmt_count 5
Qcache_free_blocks  1
Qcache_free_memory  1031360
Qcache_hits 0
Qcache_inserts  0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   499229802
Qcache_queries_in_cache 0
Qcache_total_blocks 1
Queries 1690793956
Questions   594029638
Rsa_public_key  
Select_full_join    4242
Select_full_range_join  44
Select_range    3438367
Select_range_check  0
Select_scan 16832756
Slave_heartbeat_period  0.000
Slave_last_heartbeat    
Slave_open_temp_tables  0
Slave_received_heartbeats   0
Slave_retried_transactions  0
Slave_running   OFF
Slow_launch_threads 0
Slow_queries    837
Sort_merge_passes   2098
Sort_range  250992
Sort_rows   28892235
Sort_scan   2179832
Ssl_accept_renegotiates 0
Ssl_accepts 723
Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0
Ssl_cipher  
Ssl_cipher_list 
Ssl_client_connects 0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    18446744073709551615
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode 5
Ssl_default_timeout 0
Ssl_finished_accepts    717
Ssl_finished_connects   0
Ssl_server_not_after    
Ssl_server_not_before   
Ssl_session_cache_hits  5
Ssl_session_cache_misses    655
Ssl_session_cache_mode  SERVER
Ssl_session_cache_overflows 410
Ssl_session_cache_size  128
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts  4
Ssl_sessions_reused 0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  128
Ssl_verify_depth    0
Ssl_verify_mode 0
Ssl_version 
Table_locks_immediate   2216706048
Table_locks_waited  25050917
Table_open_cache_hits   2783618885
Table_open_cache_misses 7341
Table_open_cache_overflows  615
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size    0
Tc_log_page_waits   0
Threads_cached  9
Threads_connected   20
Threads_created 402
Threads_running 3
Uptime  8001175
Uptime_since_flush_status   8001175
```

Comment: Looks like a big backup or large batch job. Check your slow query log, it looks like some some where registered about the same time.

Comment: And, how much RAM do you have?  If you have at least 6GB, then OK; if you have 3GB or less, then the buffer_pool is too big.

Comment: This is on an Amazon RDS db.t2.medium which has 4GB ram.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin helps with CPU and, in some systems, I/O: wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed

**Analysis of GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES:**

**Observations:**

- Version: 5.6.51-log
- 4 GB of RAM??
- Uptime = 92d 14:32:55
- 211 Queries/sec : 74.2 Questions/sec

**The More Important Issues:**

Suggested changes:

```
general_log = OFF   -- to avoid rapidly filling up disk
max_connections = 60
```

To advise on `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (now 2G), I need to know the RAM size (I assumed 4G for this analysis)

I see a lot of prepare+execute (69/sec) but not many proc calls. -- What API are you using to connect to mysqld?

I see an unusually high number of these; what is going on?  ALTER DATABASE, DROP/CREATE TRIGGER, FLUSH, PURGE, RENAME TABLE

`Compression = ON` -- How is that going for you?

**Details and other observations:**

`( general_log ) = general_log = ON` -- Log (FILE or TABLE) of all queries run.
-- Turn off the general_log (now ON) when not in use. That log can fill up disk very rapidly.

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 2,048 / 4096M = 50.0%` -- % of RAM used for InnoDB buffer_pool
-- Set to about 70% of available RAM. (To low is less efficient; too high risks swapping.)

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,024`
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- When flushing, use this many IOPs.
-- Reads could be slugghish or spiky.

`( innodb_io_capacity_max / innodb_io_capacity ) = 2,000 / 200 = 10` -- Capacity: max/plain
-- Recommend 2. Max should be about equal to the IOPs your I/O subsystem can handle. (If the drive type is unknown 2000/200 may be a reasonable pair.)

`( Innodb_pages_written / Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests ) = 74,268,160 / 471798585 = 15.7%` -- Write requests that had to hit disk
-- Check innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 2147483648)

`( Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group / innodb_log_file_size ) = 56,568,371,200 / (8001175 / 3600) / 2 / 128M = 0.0948` -- Ratio
-- (see minutes)

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 8,001,175 / 60 * 128M / 56568371200 = 316` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, this can be changed dynamically; be sure to also change my.cnf.
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size (now 134217728). (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- I/O ops per second capable on disk . 100 for slow drives; 200 for spinning drives; 1000-2000 for SSDs; multiply by RAID factor.

`( innodb_strict_mode ) = innodb_strict_mode = OFF` -- Catches some subtle errors earlier.
-- OFF leaves some warnings as warnings; ON makes them errors.

`( innodb_adaptive_hash_index ) = innodb_adaptive_hash_index = ON` -- Usually should be ON.
-- There are cases where OFF is better. See also innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts (after 5.7.9) and innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions (MariaDB and Percona). ON has been implicated in rare crashes (bug 73890). 10.5.0 decided to default OFF.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( character_set_server ) = character_set_server = latin1`
-- Charset problems may be helped by setting character_set_server (now latin1) to utf8mb4. That is the future default.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( Com__biggest ) = Com__biggest = Com_stmt_execute` -- Which of the "Com_" metrics is biggest.
-- Normally it is Com_select (now 499230264). If something else, then it may be a sloppy platform, or may be something else.

`( binlog_error_action ) = binlog_error_action = IGNORE_ERROR` -- What to do if the binlog cannot be written.
-- IGNORE_ERROR is the default for backwards compatibility, but ABORT_SERVER is recommended.

`( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = MIXED` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED.
-- ROW is preferred by 5.7 (10.3)

`( simplified_binlog_gtid_recovery ) = 0` -- Percona: Perform a faster crash recovery.
-- Set to 1 to speed up binlog recovery with/without GTIDs after a crash.

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( log_slow_slave_statements ) = log_slow_slave_statements = OFF` -- (5.6.11, 5.7.1) By default, replicated statements won't show up in the slowlog; this causes them to show.
-- It can be helpful in the slowlog to see writes that could be interfering with Replica reads.

`( Max_used_connections / max_connections ) = 47 / 312 = 15.1%` -- Peak % of connections
-- Since several memory factors can expand based on max_connections (now 312), it is good not to have that setting too high.

You have the Query Cache half-off. You should set both query_cache_type = OFF and query_cache_size = 0 . There is (according to a rumor) a 'bug' in the QC code that leaves some code on unless you turn off both of those settings.

**Abnormally small:**

```
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data = 236 /sec
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Com_alter_db = 0.00045 /HR
Com_create_trigger = 0.0013 /HR
Com_drop_trigger = 0.0013 /HR
Com_flush = 13 /HR
Com_purge_before_date = 12 /HR
Com_rename_table = 0.049 /HR
Com_show_privileges = 0.0022 /HR
Com_stmt_close = 69 /sec
Com_stmt_execute = 69 /sec
Com_stmt_prepare = 69 /sec
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads * innodb_page_size / innodb_buffer_pool_size = 30712.3%
Prepared_stmt_count = 5
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
Compression = ON
innodb_data_home_dir = /rdsdbdata/db/innodb
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
log_output = TABLE
optimizer_trace = enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features = greedy_search=on, range_optimizer=on, dynamic_range=on, repeated_subselect=on
relay_log_recovery = ON
slave_rows_search_algorithms = TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
time_zone = UTC
```

Comment: Where could you see these? "I see an unusually high number of these; what is going on? ALTER DATABASE, DROP/CREATE TRIGGER, FLUSH, PURGE, RENAME TABLE"

Comment: @ronnz - `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Com_%'` -- shows counters (since restart) for lots of commands and variants of commands (eg, the various `PURGEs`).  I divided by `Uptime` to get the metrics.  But... Note: mysqld has been running for 92 days.  Possibly some of that was long ago.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for reducing CPU busy in your AWS RDS Parameters group

```
read_rnd_buffer_size=65536  # from 524288 to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 171,660
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
max_connections=100  # from 312 because max_used_connections in 90+ days was 47 concurrent at one time
net_buffer_length=98304  # from 16384 to reduce sent packet count when busy
```

Observations, RAM at 4G is too small for your workload and causes innodb_data_reads.  Double RAM to minimize this specific workload 16 RPS.
Correct cause of ROLLBACK's that are intense.